# How to validate JSON received from input with the help of Typescript Interface?

Tags: json, typescript

I have an input field (text-area), which receives an array of objects in JSON format and I have to validate each of the array element at run-time based on an interface created in typescript.

I created interfaces **Employee** and **Address** with custom type **roleType**

```
interface Employee {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  email: string;
  address?: Address;
  role?: roleType;
}

interface Address{
  city: string;
  pinCode: number;
}

type roleType = 'Developer' | 'UI Designer';
```

Valid JSON:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 25,
    "email": "john@email.com",
  },
  {
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "age": 23,
    "email": "jane@email.com",
  }
]
```

Invalid JSON:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 25,
    "language": "typescript",
  },
  {
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "age": 23,
    "email": "jane@email.com",
  }
]
```

And tried using a function **checkArray** like this,

```
function checkArray(array: any[]) {
  if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
    return false;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!(array[i] instanceof Employee)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

But this does not work because interface Employee is a type and we can't use it as a value with instanceof.

How can I validate my array with interface type and generate appropriate errors without using any external libraries?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this at runtime with TypeScript because TypeScript gets transpiled down to JavaScript. `interface` is a TypeScript syntax.

You could however have a map of property names and JavaScript typeof values.

```
interface Employee {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  email: string;
  manager: {
    name: string;
  }
  skills: string[];
}

type EmployeeValidationMap = Record<keyof Employee, string> & { [key: string]: string};

const jsMapForValidation: EmployeeValidationMap = {
  name: "string",
  age: "number",
  email: "string",
  manager: "object",
  skills: "array"
}


const validate = (employee: Employee) => {
return Object.entries(employee).map(([prop, value]) => {
  let passedValidation: boolean = false;
  if (jsMapForValidation[prop] === "array") {
    passedValidation = Array.isArray(value);
  } else {
    passedValidation = typeof value === jsMapForValidation[prop]
  }
  return { [prop]: passedValidation };
})
}


const validEmployee: Employee = {
  name: "Rob",
  age: 99,
  email: "rob@rob.com",
  manager: {
    name: "Boss"
  },
  skills: ["JavaScript", "TypeScript"]
}

const invalidEmployee: Employee = {
  name: "Rob",
  age: "not a number" as any,
  email: "rob@rob.com",
  manager: undefined as any,
  skills: 123 as any,
}

// 1. Validating valid employee object (returns true if data type is expected)
console.log(validate(validEmployee));
/*}, {
  "skills": true
}] 
[LOG]: [{
  "name": true
}, {
  "age": true
}, {
  "email": true
}, {
  "manager": true
}, {
  "skills": true
}] 
*/

// 2. Validating invalid employee object (returns false if data type is not expected, in this case age is a string and not a number)
console.log(validate(invalidEmployee));
/*
[LOG]: [{
  "name": true
}, {
  "age": false     <------ Age is a number not a string
}, {
  "email": true
}, {
  "manager": false    <------ Manager is not an object
}, {
  "skills": false   <------ Skills is not an array
}] 
*/
*/
```

Here's the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIFsAOAbA9gTwhQG8AoZZEOdCALmQGcwpQBzAbnOTlbsoFd0AI2icKEdHGDZ6TFiA5dJVXlHpkKFKjVnM2Y5AF8uDANbTsDXfNYBtALqdjpMPkwoMOAkQBqcbMAAJnBgwLggALJwmMgAvMgAShAIuFCBADymEPi4MGhYeIQQADSMegoAfMgAZMjEyLZZ%20NZs9i0KhpykKSBMyABWDFGYAGKpfgHBoeH0noW%20-kEhYZHRcXVc2nwARHJs28VcPDsggiJQB1wSUjLIu%20WslxTKx2p3uEL9yWBPjObYlno2zgUCgcHw21Izm64T6ADdFlMUPEABQSLxFWYFbwQACUcSqZCgEDA-CgIGQAHlPt8AHQQcAsCAMNHYoq42mSTAolG2TBQXCYUoI7D8CD2fGxQlcbAk5CYOAMBgQQITJbTED0IS4XCyuAU%20LwSwQAzAPIowbDMZQNVTFZ8gWYexxWLxYGg8HbfEaTQKpUq23LcLrACCHvwtOADDDYPwKJFYtxBkMyAgxo2mnliuVqsRQYNyFc7lyyATyNdAyG0WtgY1DsFji4xgoxNJ5LqDX5DfofpztZWRicuKhpFHPXhiLmOKxGKI6x9WyBCQ%20v2O9AAnOvDuJJNIgQKhAABA%200lLoX4vVTqLhaag7ABCuCVkIohm3fwsVga2wAUnAEQAyggLCYD8pTbAAKm4EBASBPz2COMK9GAyCgCKQRTpi%20SzsiGaUHeS4ru%20a53CAuAoXAAjCNA2zcAw3AgPg77XHudwHseHynrg57vpe0D0PwICBBAMCgCqdEMUxJj-ICyAAIwAEwAMwSfqUnOAA9Bp8m0sg-YKKWiKpmyc4fF8CAoSirZkr0hZQGKqF5FMlFFigUapgAHu4FkqsO466hAtJ4Kw8Z5pAoWTJhRC4kmpAaQAVG%20eG7DJDDbPQzBilCzqkLYAAylIAOJtA0PrbFs6V2VlSVlcclWZRAUKlGVLHYPV9mNTVXDbHxFwZR1TXJWYn7tdVOXxRpo5acgCm6fprCoSA6GBMZOHIGZ3zIFZJI2fRRrKo5yDOYW0GofRZEoRAXnfCqpSgIWAAW7kIIqKDHGd3BlDYDErRdn2nNRUB%20bCAVBbgIXLSEEAomhk4mXisUJblBXFfQthlRV-XVc13V1fQ%200oJm6QALSk2TyAhrwH2UQD5yUORn17Aog0tbubVY51OMUD1%20qvJVBNE2T5NRCo0AfX9%20rrTSFks91w0Aml%20P%20AdFAk0LxPIABqXiwzksgrG2XIKQE1AA)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer. It is working as expected for primitive types, but for not working properly for non-primitive types such as objects, union types and nested interfaces. Could you please share something regarding that too? @Robert Rendell

Comment: I've added support for objects. Union types and interfaces can't be validated with TypeScript at runtime because at runtime it's JavaScript.

Comment: I added support for arrays too. Have a good day